# Grails Custom Validator on Property From Another Domain Class

Tags: grails-validation

New to Grails 2.0 and would appreciate any help on creating a custom validator in Evaluation that custid is in Customer.  Only existing customer can complete an evaluation.  Thanks!

class Customer {

```
String custId
String firstName
String lastName

static constraints = {
    custId()
    firstName()
    lastName()
}
```

}

class Evaluation {

```
String custId
String comment

static constraints = {
    custId()
    comment()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slight redesign and pass an instance of Customer into your Evaluation object.  Then inside Evaluation class, create a validation to ensure Customer isn't null.  What this does is leverage the Customer class validation to ensure that you have a "valid" customer id which you'll need to have anyway in order to lookup/instantiate a Customer object from the custId that I assume you're getting from the web form being submitted.

```
class Evaluation {
  Customer customer
  String comment

  static constraints = {
    customer nullable: false
  }
}
```